# How to fetch data from an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using a script to push values to a script, and I need to push a value from what I think would be an Attribue? I want to target the string inside the proid variable in the HTML below.

```
ccs_cc_args.push(['FFR_NAME', $(".infobar").text()]);
console.log(ccs_cc_args);
```

Tried to change it to something like this with a few variations, doesn't work of course.

```
ccs_cc_args.push(['CPN', $("[data-proid]").text()])
console.log(ccs_cc_args);
```

HtML:

```
<a id="prodcmp" href="javascript://" class="action" onclick="updateCompareProducts(this);" prodid="107255" compaction="0">Voeg toe om te vergelijken</a>
```

Comment: $('el').attr('attrname') returns attribute value.. since u are using jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function in jQuery to read the value of a specific attribute :

```
// This will read the prodid attribute of any elements that have that specific attribute
var prodid = $('[prodid]').attr('prodid');
```

If you wanted to target that specific element, you could use the same code but target that element by its `id` :

```
var prodid = $('#prodcmp').attr('prodid');
```

**Consider Conventional `data-*` Attributes**

Additionally, it's worth noting that if you are planning on using attributes in this manner, you should consider prefacing them with `data-`, which is a fairly standard convention :

```
<div id='foo' data-prodid='42'></div>
```

This would allow you to not only target this via the `attr()` function, but it would allow you to use the [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function as well, which is designed for reading attributes that are defined this way.

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery attr is function is used to  set and get attribute value.

For example

```
$(selector).attr('attributeName');
```

is used for fetch attribute value

```
$(selector).attr('attributeName','value');
```

is used for set attribute value

```
    <div id='productDiv' data-price='5000'></div>

    var productPrice = $('#productDiv').attr('data-price')
```

`productPrice` contain 5000